# Porting InterlockedExchange, using GCC intrinsics only

Tags: c, gcc, port, atomic

Windows API offers `InterlockedExchange`, which sets a value in memory atomically. Using only GCC intrinsics, I’d like to create an equivalent of that function. Would setting the value and then calling a memory barrier be sufficient (see the code below) ?

```
template <typename T>
T InterlockedExchange(volatile T& _data, T _value)
{
    const T oldValue = _data;
    _data = _value;
    __sync_synchronize();
    return oldValue;
}
```

Thank you.

**EDIT**: The proposed snippet is *NOT* a correct solution to the problem, as it is clearly not atomic (but, well, I had to give a try at least).

Comment: You declare the `_data` parameter as a reference, but later access it using pointer dereference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use <strike>`__sync_val_compare_and_swap`</strike>  `__sync_lock_test_and_set`, not `__sync_synchronize`.

This has exactly the same function as InterlockedExchange.

Something like this (untested code!):

```
template<typename T> T InterlockedExchange(T& data, T& new_val)
{
    return __sync_lock_test_and_set(&data, new_val);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Oi, I read wrong, you wanted InterlockedExchange, not InterlockedCompareExchange ... so that is `__sync_lock_test_and_set` (the name is a misleading Intel-nomer, but it's exactly what you want).
See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html#_005f_005fsync-Builtins), bottom of the page.

Comment: Note that `__sync_lock_test_and_set()` only has Acquire semantics, so this is equivalent only to `InterlockedExchangeAcquire()`.  You need to add a `__sync_synchronize();` for a full memory barrier, equivalent to `InterlockedExchange()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed example is not equivalent, because it is not atomic.  Two racing threads executing your function can both retrieve the same old value, with one of the new values being "lost".

Comment: Indeed, I’ll change as soon as I find a solution :)