# Multi-threading in a sender-receiver model in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to build a sender-receiver model in C++. I want to send data from sender to receiver in the feed-forward way. Shortly, the desired architecture could be expressed like so (elementary units are called *nodes*):

> Each node can receive (send) data from (to) another node. Each node has as many as desired senders (receivers). Each node has a number called *impulse* which is data supposed to be sent. Let's call one data propagation through a whole network a *cycle*. Then in one cycle each node that belongs to the network must send impulse once and only once to all its receivers.

A scratch of the implementation of the above idea is the following.

```
class Node
{
  private :
    double in_signal;//received data
    double out_signal;//data to send
    bool is_opened;//status of channel

    void update_in( double package );//receive new package

  protected :
    std::vector<Node*> receivers;

  public :
    Node( double out_signal )
    : in_signal(0.),
      out_signal(out_signal),
      is_opened(false)
    {}
    ~Node() {}

    void add_receiver( Node* receiver );
    void emit();//send out_signal or impulse
};

void Node::update_in( double package )
{
  //the problem is how to control the status of the channel:
  //it must be closed after getting all data
  if ( not is_opened )
  {
    in_signal = 0.;//reset
    is_opened = true;
  }
  in_signal += package;
}

void Node::add_receiver( Node* receiver )
{
   receivers.push_back( receiver );
}

void Node::emit()
{
   for ( auto& receiver : receivers )
   {
      receiver->update_in( out_signal );
   }
}
```

The problem I cannot solve is *multi-threading behind this architecture*:

> The node's `in_signal` can be updated by several senders, but senders work independently (required) therefore I am afraid of arising concurrency.

---

So I am asking about

1. How to solve this multi-thereading problem?
2. How to decide if all data has been received?

I will be thankful for some ideas, patterns, conceptions etc.

Comment: There's nothing in the described task that requires multithreading. Since you asked for ideas, here's an idea: take out a blank piece of paper, and write down in short, brief, English sentences your proposed algorithm for implementing this task. When you're done, [schedule an appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck reviews your plan and approves it, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, IMHO, this is an oversimplification about your problem.
I think, for example, your data couldn't be simply `double`.

Anyway:

1. If in your architecture you have a race condition (if each node has it's own thread, you clearly have a race condition), i don't see any solution but `mutex`.
2. It depens on real task vastity and complexity, but you could apply some rule to let nodes be capable of understand lifetime of packets (some ideas: sequence number for packets, list of near nodes, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

To protect a variable I recommend you use a test-and-set method, which is a simple mechanism for synchronizing access to a variable that is shared by multiple threads.

In `Windows` the most common way to do that is by using the [InterlockedExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683590(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

For linux just use this wrapper [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268243/porting-interlockedexchange-using-gcc-intrinsics-only):

```
template<typename T> T InterlockedExchange(T& data, T& new_val)
{
    return __sync_lock_test_and_set(&data, new_val);
}
```